# How to query on AWS Athena for .csv file's creation or last modification date

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

With AWS Athena it is easily to query for .csv file's name using this:

```
select "$path", * from my_table;
```

I wonder if it is possible to also do the same for the creation or modification timestamps:

```
select "$creation_date" from my_table;    
select "$modification_date" from my_table;
```

I could not find anything regarding this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option as of today in Athena. Athena uses [PrestoDB](https://prestodb.io/) and this [feature](https://github.com/trinodb/trino/pull/1428) has been introduced in Trino (formerly prestosql).

Have filed a [request](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/16054) for the same with PrestoDB.